# Custom binding for when foreach has finished rendering

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have an observable array with items bound to an `ul`. I need to calculate the width of the entire set of `li` items once the items have been added so I can set the width of the `ul` element to the total width of the child `li` elements.

How can I go about doing this with a `foreach` binding?

```html
<div>
    <h2 data-bind="visible: items().length">Test</h2>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, afterAdd: $root.myAfterAdd }">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two" },
        { name: "three" }
        ]),
    myAfterAdd: function(element) {
        if (element.nodeType === 1) {
           alert("myAfterAdd");   
        }
    },
    addItem: function() {
        this.items.push({ name: 'new' });
    }
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// once foreach has finished rendering I have to set the width 
// of the ul to be the total width of the children!
```

I tried using `afterAdd` so I can 'update' the width of the `ul` after each element is added, unfortunately I have discovered that `afterAdd` does not fire for the initial items! It will only fire when pushing *additional* items...

Note that the content inside the `li` items will be of unknown width :)

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLXUb/5/) for a sample scenario.

Comment: `afterRender` does what you want, and runs after the initial render.

Comment: Problem with `afterRender` is that it is called before the dom element is completely initialized (e.g. li item), this is giving me incorrect widths.

Comment: On a side note, I'm mighty curious: *why* would you want to do this?

Comment: I need to create a side scroller for the list items. That is why I need to set the width!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much 'googling' I have found the solution. The way to achieve this with a foreach is too register a custom event handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.runafter = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        setTimeout(function (element, value) {
            if (typeof value != 'function' || ko.isObservable(value))
                throw 'run must be used with a function';

            value(element);
        }, 0, element, value);
    }
};
```

This handler will fire whenever an update occurs (or just once if value is not an observable).

More importantly it will fire once the foreach loop has completed!

See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/kApcc36lRxU).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. You can use this to make that initial calculation:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mybinding {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var foreach = allBindings().foreach,
                subscription = foreach.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                // do something here (e.g. calculate width/height, use element and its children)
                subscription.dispose(); // dispose it if you want this to happen exactly once and never again.
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
var viewModel = {
    items: ko.observableArray([
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two" },
        { name: "three" }
        ]),
    myAfterAdd: function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent.srcElement.nodeType === 1) {
           alert("myAfterAdd");   
        }
    },
    addItem: function() {
        this.items.push({ name: 'new' });
    }
};


$('#bucket').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', viewModel.myAfterAdd);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Which bucket is the ul element

**[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLXUb/8/)**

I hope it helps